# Pandas Number of Unique Values and sort by the number of unique

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to count the number of unique items grouped by a value and sorted by the count of the unique items per group.

For example

```
   A  B
0  C  A
1  C  C
2  D  C
3  D  J
4  D  F
5  E  C
6  E  C
```

The output should show

```
   A  count
0  D      3
1  C      2
2  E      1
```

I'm currently using the below where I can get the unique count but not the sorting

```
df.groupby('A').B.nunique()
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you need add [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sort_values.html) + [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
df = df.groupby('A')['B'].nunique().sort_values(ascending=False).reset_index(name='count')
print (df)
   A  count
0  D      3
1  C      2
2  E      1
```