# Sorting unique values according to another column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to sort unique values in pandas dataframe with group by;

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
...     'gr1': ['A', 'A', 'A','A', 'B', 'B', 'B','B'],
        'gr1_sum' : [100,100 ,100,100, 200,200,200,200],
        'rank_gr1': [2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1],

...     'gr2': ['a1', 'a1', 'a2','a2',  'b1', 'b1', 'b2','b2'],
        'gr2_sum' : [30,30 ,40,40, 20,20,10,10]})

#df.sort_values(by=['col2'],inplace = True)    
rank_gr1_sort = pd.unique(df['rank_gr1'].values)
rank_gr2_sort = df.sort_values(['rank_gr1']).groupby(['gr1','gr2'])['gr2_sum'].unique()

rank_gr1_sort
array([2, 1], dtype=int64)

rank_gr2_sort
gr1  gr2
A    a1     [30]
     a2     [40]
B    b1     [20]
     b2     [10]
Name: gr2_sum, dtype: object
```

What I need to have is this;

```
   gr1  gr2
    B    b1     [20]
         b2     [10]
    A    a1     [30]
         a2     [40]
    Name: gr2_sum, dtype: object
```

How I do achive this output ?

Thx!

[pandas groupby sort within groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27842613/pandas-groupby-sort-within-groups)

[Pandas Number of Unique Values and sort by the number of unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48162201/pandas-number-of-unique-values-and-sort-by-the-number-of-unique)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass `sort=False` under the groupby.

From docs:

> sort : bool, default True
>   Sort group keys. Get better performance by turning this off. Note this does not influence the order of observations within each group. Groupby preserves the order of rows within each group.

```
rank_gr2_sort = df.sort_values(['rank_gr1']).groupby(
                       ['gr1','gr2'],sort=False)['gr2_sum'].unique()
```

---

```
gr1  gr2
B    b1     [20]
     b2     [10]
A    a1     [30]
     a2     [40]
Name: gr2_sum, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! If choose to do `df.groupby(['gr1','gr2'])['gr2_sum'].unique()` where should I put the `sort_values`. combining other functions and groupby always confuses me!